# Extracting first occurrence node values from xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Below is my XML and I need to extract the first occurrence of required value.

```
<abc>
    <bcd> 
        <jhk> 
            <lmn>fsdfsdfsdf</lmn>
            <dfg>4500</dfg>
        </jkk>
    </bcd>
    <bcd> 
        <jhk> 
            <lmn>fsdfsdfsdf</lmn>
            <dfg>4567</dfg>
        </jkk>
    </bcd>
    <bcd> 
        <jhk> 
            <lmn>fsdfsdfsdf</lmn>
            <dfg>4566</dfg>
        </jkk>
    </bcd>
    <bcd> 
        <jhk> 
            <lmn>fsdfsdfsdf</lmn>
            <dfg>4566</dfg>
        </jkk>
    </bcd>
    <bcd> 
        <jhk> 
            <lmn>fsdfsdfsdf</lmn>
            <dfg>4567</dfg>
        </jkk>
    </bcd>
    <def> 
        <hgj>fsdf</hgj>
    </def>
</abc>
```

he requirement is to get value of abc/bcd/jhk/lmn where abc/bcd/jhk/dfg = 4566 at the first occurrence. how do I get this using javascript

Here's what I tried

```
xml.item(0).forEach(element => {
    if (element.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "jhk").item(0).getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "dfg").item(0).textContent === "4566") {
        let reqVal = getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "lmn").item(0).textContent;
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the o/p that you are getting?

Comment: @Atk What does "o/p" mean?

Comment: @Cully It means output.

Comment: Actually no output.